# Modifying Bootstrap Collapse: make content appear to the right of tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to modify Twitter Bootstrap's Collapse code so that the content appears on the right instead of directly below the tabs.

I've got that set up, but the problem is is that the active tab doesn't close when another tab is clicked. Below is my code. The problem can be viewed here: http://www.reeldealoffshore.com

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- end col-sm-6 -->
<div class="col-sm-6">  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div> </div>  <div class="panel panel-default"> <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">  
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div></div><div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">  
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div></div>
    </div>

</div><!-- end col-sm-6 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/ejnv8/

Just a little bit of jQuery to manipulate the order they expand/collapse.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".collapse").collapse('hide');
    $("#accordion a").click(function() {
        $(".collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
});
```